# Solve exponential equation $17 \cdot 64^{x} - 4 \cdot 8^{x} - 164 = - 42 \cdot 8^{1-x} + 2 \cdot 8^{2-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

I tried to solve this exponential equation but got only one of the two solutions right.

This is what I did:
$$
17 \cdot 64^{x} - 4 \cdot 8^{x} - 164 = - 42 \cdot 8^{1-x} + 2 \cdot 8^{2-x}
$$
I set everything to one side:
$$
\Leftrightarrow 17 \cdot 64^{x} - 4 \cdot 8^{x} - 164 + 42 \cdot 8^{1-x} - 2 \cdot 8^{2-x} = 0
\\
\Leftrightarrow 17 \cdot \left({8^x}\right)^2 - 4 \cdot 8^{x} - 164 + 42 \cdot 8^{1} \cdot 8^{x^{-1}} - 2 \cdot 8^{2} \cdot 8^{-x} = 0
$$
I then replaced $8^x$ with y
$$
\Leftrightarrow 17 \cdot y^2 - 4y - 164 + 336 y^{-1} - 128 y^{-1} = 0
\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{17 \cdot y³ - 4y² - 164y + 336 - 128}{y} = 0
\\
\Leftrightarrow 17y^3 - 4y^2 - 164y + 208 = 0 \ \text{ ($y$ is NOT 0)}
\\
(\ldots)
\\
\Leftrightarrow y = 2\text{ or }17y^2 + 30y - 104 = 0
\\
D = b^2 - 4ac\\
  = 7972
\\
y = 1,743707056\ \text{ (also a negative solution which I leave behind)}
\\
y = 2 \text{ or } y = 1,743707056
\\
\Leftrightarrow 8^x = 2 \text{ or } 8^x = 1,743707056
\\
\Leftrightarrow \log 8^x = 2 \text{ or } \log 8^x = 1,743707056
\\
\Leftrightarrow \ldots 
\\
\Leftrightarrow x = \frac13 \text{ or } x = 0,26739
$$
$x = \frac13$ is a correct solution
$x = 0,26729$ is a false solution, but I can't see where I'm wrong if someone can help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: actually, $x \approx 0.267386$ is correct, it is $ \frac{\log 1.743707563005848813843004478}{  \log 8}$

Comment: J.W. Tanner I followed the rules for exponents but the exponent doesn't show.

Comment: Thank you Will Jagy, I entered the fraction you gave me in my calculator and it said now that it is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoe to address a comment to a user, begin the message with an @ sign and the beginning of the username. That way, if they have left this question (but are still on the site), they  get a little red flag with a link to your comment.  About mathjax, it is likely you did not put dollar $ signs on both sides of each equation

Comment: Thanks @WillJagy, will remember this for the next time I post something on this forum.

Comment: What makes you say that it is a false solution ?